# Android skipping over lines of code in progam

Tags: android, android-file

I want to start out by saying that I am a big newbie I have only been working on this for about 4 days and that includes reading many pages of a java reference book.

The point of this app is to take information from a text file and then do very little math with it and then return a value. I have gotten it to work on the emulator on my computer running android 5.1.1 but when I run it on my note 4 running 6.0.1 it just skips lines of code in debug mode and I don't understand why.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView output;

    EditText food;
    EditText block;
    EditText ounce;

    Button calculate_blocks;
    Button calculate_ounces;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        //finding elements
        output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);

        food = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.food);
        block = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.blocks);
        ounce = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ounces);

        calculate_ounces = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate_ounces);
        calculate_blocks = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate_blocks);


        //setting listeners
        calculate_blocks.setOnClickListener(this);
        calculate_ounces.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        final String FILENAME = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Foods.txt";

        BufferedReader fin = null;
        FileReader fr = null;

        String currentLine="zeutn", line=null ;
        String strfood = food.getText().toString();
        double gramsOfNutrientPerOunce=0;
        double ounces=0,blocks=0;

        try {
            ounces = Double.parseDouble(ounce.getText().toString());
        }   catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
            ounces=0;
        }

        try {
            blocks = Double.parseDouble(block.getText().toString());
        }   catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
            blocks=0;
        }


        //Find refrence value after food in file

        try {
            File file1 = new File(FILENAME);
            file1.createNewFile();
            fr = new FileReader(FILENAME);
            fin = new BufferedReader(fr);

            while ((currentLine = fin.readLine()) != null) {
                if ((currentLine.toUpperCase()).equals(strfood.toUpperCase())) {
                    line = fin.readLine();
                    fr.close();
                    fin.close();
                } else
                    output.setText("Add food to file");
            }

        }   catch (IOException e) {
            output.setText("Fail");
            }


        try{
            gramsOfNutrientPerOunce=Double.parseDouble(line);
        }   catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
            output.setText("Add food to file");
        }

        String out;
        double tmp;
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.calculate_blocks:
                tmp = ounces/gramsOfNutrientPerOunce;
                out=Double.toString(tmp);

                output.setText(out);
                break;

            case R.id.calculate_ounces:
                tmp = blocks*gramsOfNutrientPerOunce;
                out=Double.toString(tmp);

                output.setText(out);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated sorry if I'm doing this all wrong also so if you need more information or anything I will be happy to provide it.Thank you much in advance!!

Comment: post the error log. What do you mean be skipping lines?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have Runtime permissions for Api level 23 (Android 6.0) and above. The way you can do that is pretty simple.

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```

Then what ever response the user gives you can handle it in the callback method, which goes something like this.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

Note: coding sample is taken from https://developer.android.com

And one more thing that i notice is that you have setOnClickListeners to your buttons, but in your onClick Method you are not handling it so both the buttons when clicked will perform the exact same thing. you can handle them simply by switch view.getID or in your case v.getID, the code goes something like this.

```
switch (v.getId()){

    case R.id.(id_of_firstButton):
        //do what you have to do for first button
        break;
    case R.id.(id_of_secondButton):
        //do what you have to do for second button
        break;
    default:
        //do something in the default case
        break; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know which lines are skipping but seems like Read/Write permissions are missing.

You need to check your permissions on runtime with Android 6.0 and above.

[Documentation For Runtime Permissions.](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)